$g(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ a fixed point iteration. Given $g(p)=p, \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p-x_{n+1}}{p-x_n}=g'(p)$ find an upper bound for $p-x_n$
Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ , defined as: $g(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ a fixed point iteration, suppose there exists $p$ such that
$g(p)=p$
Given
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p-x_{n+1}}{p-x_n}=g'(p)$ , find an upper bound for $|p-x_n|$
Edit: we may observe $g$ on the interval: $[x_0, x_n]$, Let it be denoted as: $[a,b]$, such that for every $x_j:  g(x_j)\in [a, b]$, and, of course, $g(p)=p\in [a, b]$, such that such upper bound will be in respective to $[a,b]$.
My Attempt:
My problem is that I don't understand what kind of a conclusion can be made about $g'(p)$, given the expression: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p-x_{n+1}}{p-x_n}= 
g'(p)$.
As
$g(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} g(x_n) = p$, we derive:
$
g'(p) = \lim_{x\to p} \frac{g(x) - g(p)}{x-p} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(x_n) - p}{x_n - p} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1} - p}{x_n - p} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p - x_{n+1}}{p - x_n}
$
Which is, we know that there exists a derivative in $x=p$, as it is literally the definition of a derivative.
How can one remove the limit and to conclude anything about $|p-x_n|$, as we do not have any bound over $|g'(p)|$.

Generally, it is possible that there is no upper bound for $|p-x_n|$.
For instance, take $g(x)=2x$ and $p=0$. $x_n=-2n$ satisfies the condition and $\lim_{n\to \infty}(p-x_n)$ tends to infinity. If one can show $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=p$, then there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n> N$ (...). One possible upper bound is $\max{|p-x_1|,\ldots,|p-x_{N}|}$.

What are your conditions on $g$? Is it differentiable? Maybe defined on a compact set or something like that? Maybe you can invoke the mean value theorem...

@BoweiTang this is of course true. I edited the question.

@GhostAmarth $g$ is differentiable in $x=p$, defined on $\mathbb{R}$

There is little that can be done without further assumptions, but in this context it is reasonable to assume that $$|g'(p)|<1.$$ Otherwise, there would be little reason to consider the functional iteration $$x_{k+1} = g(x_k).$$ By assumption we have that
$$ \frac{p - x_{n+1}}{p - x_n} \rightarrow g'(p), \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
Now choose any $L \in (|g'(p)|,1)$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ \left| \frac{p - x_{n+1}}{p - x_n} \right| < L$$
for all $n \ge N$. It follows that
$$ | p - x_{N+k} | \leq L^k |p - x_N|.$$

The main point is that
$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{p - x_{n+1}}{p - x_n} \right| = |g'(p)|<k<1$, hence,
$|p-x_{n}|\leq |(g'(p))^{k}| \cdot |p - x_{n+1}|, \forall n>N$

@NoaEven: I don't think you meant to raise $g'(p)$ to the power of $k$. You meant to write $|p-x_n| \leq |g'(p)||p - x_{n+1}|$, right? Still, we cannot actually do this, which is why I picked $L > |g'(p)|$.
